# jquery animation trigger click

Tags: jquery, animation

I have an element in my body that I animate whith this function:

```
$(function(){
    $("#telefonofisso").click(function(){
        if ($("#telefonofisso").hasClass('negative')) {
            $(this).delay(400).animate({right:'10px'},1000).addClass('positive').removeClass('negative')
        }
    });
})
```

But I can't make it return to its original `right:-210px` position if I click on it another time. I tried with the following function:

```
$(function(){
   $("#telefonofisso").click(function(){
    if ($("#telefonofisso").hasClass('positive')) {
         (this).delay(400).animate({right:'-210px'},1000).addClass('negative').removeClass('positive')
    }
  });
})
```

But this function activates before I click for the second time, so my element, if I click on it, starts from `right:-210px`, goes to `right:10px` than returns to `right:-210px` just with one click.

How can I fix that, and why does it act like that? I cannot understand the reason why it does that. Because theoretically the trigger is the click, and the second function should only act when I click for the second time, right?

Comment: Use a combined Click function handler for both conditions. As you have two click handlers, they are getting executed simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, I can see that they are executed simultaneously, but it doesn't make much sense to me, because the second one should only activate if my element has the class 'positive', and it can have just 'positive' or 'nagative' at a time. so one of the two shouldn't work.

Comment: `addClass('positive')` is executed before the animate end. Use it in animate callback function. I would demonstrate if you create a JSfiddle of your problem

Comment: Yes, but that event happens still after the click. And the second function has a click trigger. The second shouldn't work. Because it's like: when you click on it, and the element has 'positive' as a class, then do something. But right after I clicked it hasn't yet that class, because it's added in the first function. Now, I'll just take that as it is, it doesn't work. I'm just saying that tecnically, it should.

Comment: Can you make a JSfiddle of your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your goodwill, but it's not necessary. I'll go with the function in the answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
   $("#telefonofisso").click(function(){
    if ($("#telefonofisso").hasClass('positive')) {
        $(this).delay(400).animate({right:'-210px'},1000)
              .addClass('negative').removeClass('positive');
    } else {
        $(this).delay(400).animate({right:'10px'},1000)
              .addClass('positive').removeClass('negative');      
    }
  });
});
```

This will solve your problem.

And you have forgot $ sign in second call.

Answer (score 1):

Try this working demo, as per your requirement

```
  $(function(){
        $("#telefonofisso").click(function(){
            var modified = $('.slider').css('left') === '250px' ? '0px' : '250px';            
            $('.slider').animate( {            
                left : modified
            }, 300)
        });
    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/02e11v2p/1/

Comment: Thanks, your answer is interesting! Can you explain the sintax ' === '250px' ? '0px' : '250px';'     I've never seen it before, what does it do?

Comment: I'm using javascript comparison operators & ternary operator this operator takes three operands & also a shorcut for if statement. Like wise first I'm checking that the class with "slider" contains left position 250px than again setting the left position to 0px.